# Accessing a custom object inside a Codeigniter 4 model

Tags: codeigniter, object, model, codeigniter-4

I am using CodeIginter 4 and I have instantiated a new object in a controller, from a class in my app/libraries folder as such:

```
// in controller
use App\Libraries\LN_Account;

// in controller method
$account = new LN_Account();
```

But when I pass $account to my model and check if it is an instance of LN_Account the conditional fails.

```
// in controller method
$account = $this->AuthenticationModel->getAuthenticationCredentials($account); 

// in model
public function getAuthenticationCredentials($account) {
    if ($account instanceof LN_Account) {
         // I never get here
     }
}
```

How do I make LN_Account visible to my model?

The error I get is that LN_Account does not exist. It exists in the controller just fine. In CI3 anything available in the controller was available in the model. Did that change?

Comment: Can you post the exact error log for this ?
Try ```is_a()``` instead of ```instanceof```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it did change; the 'super object' you're referring to isn't 'a thing' in CI4. You can still check if something is an `instanceof` just fine; it's just that the Model doesn't automatically 'know' what/where `LN_Account` is just because you `use`d it in the Controller.

You can do one of two things:

1. Tell the Model class what and where `LN_Account` is up-front by adding `use App\Libraries\LN_Account;` into your Model code, or
2. Simply reference `LN_Account` by its full namespace when using `instanceof` (or any statement that needs to reference that class).